# Winamp - HLS radio (m3u8)

Tags: http-live-streaming, winamp

I had been listening to Music Choice through various URL's but recently they had a major makeover and are now using HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) instead of more traditional forms of streaming (this is an example URL: http://arcostream.mpl.miisolutions.n.../playlist.m3u8). I am able to play the URL with VLC and in several iOS based players but Winamp chokes on it. Is there a setting or plugin that supports HLS? Google searches and searching these forums has not come up with any hits.

I have decomposed the URL contents manually and the stream serves three 10 second chunks at a time in AAC format. Those chunks play fine in Winamp so there is no problem with the content, just acquiring the content since HLS requires constant polling of the server to continuously download chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small tool that allow Winamp to work on HLS radio stream, basically the software will allow you to convert an HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) radio source (m3u8 file extension) to the old HTTP streaming format.

You can download the source code and the software at :
https://github.com/massej/RadioHLSConverter.backend.serverless

Enjoy listening music to your favourite HLS radio station in Winamp!